# Pandas: apply a function with columns and a variable as argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm trying to apply to a dataframe a function that has more than one argument, of which two need to be assigned to the dataframe's rows, and one is a variable (a simple number).

A variation from a similar thread works for the rows: (all functions are oversimplified compared to my original ones)

```
import pandas as pd

dict={'a':[-2,5,4,-6], 'b':[4,4,5,-8]}

df=pd.DataFrame (dict)
print(df)

def DummyFunction (row):
    return row['a']*row['b']
#this works:
df['Dummy1']=df.apply(DummyFunction, axis=1)
```

But how can I apply the following variation, where my function takes in an additional argument (a fixed variable)? I seem to find no way to pass it inside the apply method:

```
def DummyFunction2(row, threshold):
    return row['a']*row['b']*threshold
# where threshold will be assigned to a number?
# I don't seem to find a viable option to fill the row argument below:
# df['Dummy2']=df.apply(DummyFunction2(row,1000), axis=1)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the additional variable directly as a named argument to `pd.DataFrame.apply`:

```
def DummyFunction2(row, threshold):
    return row['a']*row['b']*threshold

df['Dummy2'] = df.apply(DummyFunction2, threshold=2, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi @jpp, you can't understand how grateful I am. I couldn't find anything on this in any online tutorial. Thank you!